# Plesk - http access without domain - using plesk-site-preview forever?

Tags: plesk

I want to store data for an android app on the server and make in accessable over http for API without having a domain

When I create a "website" in plesk like example.com without registering any domain then I am able to access the data like: `IP/plesk-site-preview/example.com/`

But the question is can I do it forever? does it has any disadvantages? Is there a "pretier" way than `plesk-site-preview`? Like `IP/example/` for example?

I'm using Plesk Onyx 17.8.11

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In Plesk, go to Tools & Settings > IP Addresses > click on a public IP address, to which the required domain is assigned in Plesk > select an offline website as a Default site from the drop-down menu.

Now, to access the domain, type in the public IP address chosen above in a web-browser: http://203.0.112.2:80.